# Can a process in kernel context sleep while holding a mutex?

Tags: linux, kernel, mutex

I know kernel allows a process to sleep while holding a mutex (even though it is not a good practice). My question is does that necessarily mean that the process will get `pre-empted?` LKD says every time I acquire the lock the `process->thread_info->preempt_count` will be increased and schedule() checks for `preempt_count` before calling the scheduler.

So will the sleeping thread will not lead be pre-empted and keep hogging the system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a **mutex** holder is perfectly allowed to sleep.

---

> LKD says every time I acquire the lock the `process->thread_info->preempt_count` will be increased ...

This is about **spinlocks**, not *mutexes*. A **spinlock** holder is actually forbidden to sleep.